# R function to approximate geometric series

Tags: r, geometry

I would like to ask how to calculate an approximation for simple geometric series (examples bellow) using R and without loops.

> 1-(1/3)+(1/5)-(1/7)+(1/9)-(1/11)
>
> 1+(1/3^2)+(1/5^2)+(1/7^2)+(1/9^2)

I have no idea how to calculate approximation for geometric series using R, although it might be quite simple. Please help me :)

I tried to create a function, but because I'm not familiar with geometry itself I failed.

Comment: similar: `sum((-1)^(i-1)/(i*2-1))` for the first, `sum(1/(i*2-1)^2)` for the second where `i <- 1:6` and `i <- 1:5`, respectively

Answer (score 1):

We could create a sequence vector with `seq`, multiply the alternate elements with `-1` to change the sign ('v2'), divide and get the `sum`

```
v1 <- seq(3, 11, by = 2)
v2 <- rep(c(-1, 1), length.out = length(v1))
sum(c(1, v2 * (1/v1)))
[1] 0.7440115
```

Or may also use

```
sum(1/seq(1, 11, by = 2) *c(1, -1))
[1] 0.7440115
```

checking with OP's output

```
> 1-(1/3)+(1/5)-(1/7)+(1/9)-(1/11)
[1] 0.7440115
```

For second case,

```
v11 <- seq(1, 9, by = 2)
sum(1/v11^2)
[1] 1.183865
```

OP's output

```
> 1+(1/3^2)+(1/5^2)+(1/7^2)+(1/9^2)
[1] 1.183865
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Have you noticed minus signs in the first example?..

Comment: @DariaKostiniuk that is the reason I created `v2` and multiplied it with v1